# Add PPA in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, ppa, texlive

I'm very new in Ubuntu. I'm trying to upgrade my texlive in ubuntu 16.04 from 2015 to 2017 following [this](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2017) instruction. I have added these 2 file to my source list :

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2017/ubuntu xenial main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2017/ubuntu xenial main
```

And I run  `sudo apt-get update` successfully !

but in next step I'm facing with error :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2017
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~jonathonf/ubuntu/texlive-2017'.
ERROR: '~jonathonf' user or team does not exist.
```

I did also :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

and repeat the process but no chance ! Would be grateful if somebody could help ?!

Comment: Why are you trying to add the ppa twice?  The manual adding to your source.list should be enough without the needed for add-apt-repository.  Make sure you add the key though before update:  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys f06fc659`

Comment: @Terrance, Thanks for the reply. I the link that I have mentioned above, there are 2 key :`Signing key:
4096R/4AB0F789CBA31744CC7DA76A8CF63AD3F06FC659`
`Fingerprint:
4AB0F789CBA31744CC7DA76A8CF63AD3F06FC659` . I don't know what are they ?! and what should I do with those ?

Comment: The Key when you add it is the last 8 digits of the long code before the (What is this?)

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys f06fc659
Executing: /tmp/tmp.73ycZKoZFA/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
f06fc659
gpg: requesting key F06FC659 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection refused
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found`

Comment: Is your connection to the internet working correctly?

Comment: Yes ! As you see I'm online now !

Comment: Are you connecting to AskUbuntu from the same computer as you are trying to install this PPA? Are you connecting via a proxy?

Comment: Yes. Is the same connection and no proxy setting

Comment: The same connection and no proxy setting, but is it the same computer?

Comment: What does `ping ppa.launchpad.net` return?

Comment: @Terrance, `ping ppa.launchpad.net
PING ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=17.7 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=19.5 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=18.2 ms

--- ppa.launchpad.net ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.782/18.511/19.573/0.591 ms`

Comment: Ping works now (good time intervals, no packet loss). Maybe the other commands work, if you try now.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2017/ubuntu xenial InRelease
`

Comment: `Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vlc/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:6 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ InRelease
Hit:7 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease
Hit:8 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ Release
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 102 kB in 10s (9,887 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done`

Answer (score 0):

You need not add the PPA twice. The easy way is via `add-apt-repository`. You find the PPA at this link,

[launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2017](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2017)

and it describes how to use it,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2017
sudo apt-get update
```

These commands work for me (I tested in 16.04.1 LTS - live). Maybe there was a temporary glitch. Maybe there was an error because you try to add the PPA twice.

Comment: I have mentioned that like you referred to in my question ! my problem is when I run the cammand that you mentioned, I'm getting error `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~jonathonf/ubuntu/texlive-2017'.
ERROR: '~jonathonf' user or team does not exist.`

Comment: Strange that it works for me but not for you. What happens if you try again?

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini, Maybe you can remove those lines, that you added manually into your `sources.list` file. And after that try via `add-apt-repository`. This way you need not add the key separately (it should work automatically).